# Install codeigniter in parallels plesk server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, networking, server

The server runs 5.4.3  PHP with FastCGI

For Cpanel, it works perfectly, however, it fail in plesk server.

Here is the .htaccess used:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|upload|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

In config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

When I enter the home page, it shows:

```
Welcome to Parallels!

If you are seeing this message, the website for kotechweb.com is not available at this time.
If you are the owner of this website, one of the following things may be occurring:

You have not put any content on your website.
Your provider has suspended this page.
```

If I  don't use .htaccess, then it is a codeigniter 404 not found page. And it can go (although with a lot of error)

```
mydomin.com/my_folder/index.php/welcome/
```

eg.

```
Message: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/lib/php/session) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/my_domain.com/:/tmp/)

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 115
```

And a lot mkdir , session error...

also can not go other controller, it show 404 codeigniter not found page

Any way to debug and fix it? Thanks

Comment: it is the domain default page when I enter the home page , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out how to fix it at last.

First , make sure the controller class file name is in Capital letter. Lower case file name works in Apache but not the fastcgi.

Second, change the htaccess to :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Right must have every controller class name start with capital letter and on second hand .htaccess file behaves very differently on Plesk server also php_value not working and many more. Hey, I also facing a problem with mail() using Gmail on Plesk server but get may type of error. If you have any idea about it. It will be really great for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this go to php settings -> open_basedir turn it to none
worked for me
with htaccess above